# How to Map to Generic Type?

Tags: java, mapstruct

`PageInfoDto<T>`:

```
public class PageInfoDto<T> {
    private int currentPageNum;
    private int totalPageNum;
    private int perPageNum;
    private int totalItemNum;
    private List<T> list;
}
```

`Page<T>`:

```
public class Page<T> {
    private int current;
    private int total;
    private int size;
    private int items;
    private List<T> list;
}
```

I have a school list and a student list.

I want to map `Page<School>` to `PageInfoDto<SchoolDto>` and map  `Page<Student>` to `PageInfoDto<StudentDto>`。

This is how my mapper looks like:

```
@Mapper(config = CentralConfig.class, uses = {StudentMapper.class, SchoolMapper.class}, componentModel = "spring")
public interface PageInfoMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "list", source = "pageInfo.records"),
        @Mapping(target = "currentPageNum", source = "pageInfo.current"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalPageNum", source = "pageInfo.pages"),
        @Mapping(target = "perPageNum", source = "pageInfo.size"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalItemNum", source = "pageInfo.total"),
    })
    PageInfoDto<SchoolDto> toPageInfoDto1(Page<School> pageInfo);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "list", source = "pageInfo.records"),
        @Mapping(target = "currentPageNum", source = "pageInfo.current"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalPageNum", source = "pageInfo.pages"),
        @Mapping(target = "perPageNum", source = "pageInfo.size"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalItemNum", source = "pageInfo.total"),
    })
    PageInfoDto<StudentDto> toPageInfoDto2(Page<Student> pageInfo);
}
```

This is obviously not a clever way to do, having to repeat the same code. Is there a better way to do this？

Answer (score 11):

Mapstruct is a code generator. So it needs to know which types to construct in order to generate a method implementation. Having said that, you could do this smarter by using a base mapping method on which you define all the `@Mapping` annotations and ignore the generic type mapping. You still have the methods above but you just specify `@InheritConfiguration`

Alternatively you could consider playing around with an objectfactory using `@TargetType` to construct the proper generic type. I'm not sure whether that works with a generic mapping method signature. I'm not in the position to check it, but let me know if that works

E.g.

```
    public interface BasePageMapper<S, DTO> {

        @Mapping(target = "list", source = "records"),
        @Mapping(target = "currentPageNum", source = "current"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalPageNum", source = "pages"),
        @Mapping(target = "perPageNum", source = "size"),
        @Mapping(target = "totalItemNum", source = "total"),
        PageInfoDto<DTO> toPageInfoDto(Page<S> pageInfo);

        DTO toDto(S source);
    }

@Mapper( config = CentralConfig.class, uses = StudentMapper.class, componentModel = "spring")
    public interface StudentMapper extends BasePageMapper<Student, StudentDto> {

    }

@Mapper( config = CentralConfig.class, uses = SchoolMapper.class, componentModel = "spring")
    public interface SchoolMapper extends BasePageMapper<School, SchoolDto> {

    }
```

Comment: thanks。@InheritConfiguration makes the mapper look much better. but i still have to define lots of method.  toPageInfoDto1  toPageInfoDto2 toPageInfoDto3 toPageInfoDto4……  how sad. 

And about the @TargetType，i dont know exactly how to do.

Comment: We have a unit test that covers generic factories. Have a look here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/ap/test/factories/GenericFactory.java. it's not quite your scenario, and to be honest, I'm not sure at ask whether mapstruct can generate a method when it's signature contains type variables. It can select those, so you might go the other way around, so that might be an option as well.

Comment: So with the other way around I mean that you implement a generic default method with the signature you desire and then from that method call a non parameterized mapstruct method with all the mappings you desire, but ignoring the list

Comment: I've edited the answer and provided an example (from what I thought @Sjaak was thinking)