# MapStruct problem involving complex conversion and generic types

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm using ValueObjects to reduce primitive obesssion. To avoid unnecessary annotations on the mappers, I also use a special ValueObjectMapper. Normally, the mapping would look like this:

```
@Mapper
abstract class MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id.value")
    abstract TargetClass map(SourceClass source);
}
```

Because of the ValueObjectMapper, I can do without the annotation:

```
@Mapper(uses = ValueObjectMapper.class)
abstract class MyMapper {

    abstract TargetClass map(SourceClass source);
}
```

For this to work, all value objects must implement this generic ValueObject interface:

```
interface ValueObject<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

The ValueObjectMapper looks like this:

```
class ValueObjectMapper {
    static <V extends ValueObject<T>, T> T mapToValue(V valueObject) {
        return valueObject == null ? null : valueObject.getValue();
    }
}
```

This all works like a charm. However, a problem occurred when I wanted to further convert the result of the ValueOjbectMapper. A UUID should also be converted into a string. Then I got this error message:

```
incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
```

The generated source code looks like this. Unfortunately it does not hand over the result to the `map(UUID)` method:

```
class MyMapperImpl extends MyMapper {

    @Override
    TargetClass map(SourceClass source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = ValueObjectMapper.mapToValue( source.getId() );
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        TargetClass targetClass = new TargetClass( id );

        return targetClass;
    }
}
```

It seems that MapStruct is not able to further process the result of the ValueObjectMapper. Have I made a mistake or is this a bug of MapStruct?

Here is the complete code:

```
package valueobject;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.UUID;

interface ValueObject<T> {
    T getValue();
}

@Mapper(uses = ValueObjectMapper.class)
abstract class MyMapper {

    abstract TargetClass map(SourceClass source);

    String map(UUID uuid) {
        return uuid.toString();
    }
}

class ValueObjectMapper {
    static <V extends ValueObject<T>, T> T mapToValue(V valueObject) {
        return valueObject == null ? null : valueObject.getValue();
    }
}

class SomeId implements ValueObject<UUID> {
    private final UUID value;

    public SomeId(UUID value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class SourceClass {
    private final SomeId id;

    public SourceClass(SomeId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public SomeId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class TargetClass {
    private final String id;

    public TargetClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

        SomeId id = new SomeId(UUID.fromString("F0E11AE8-6510-4F4D-B4D4-96C11A891606"));
        SourceClass source = new SourceClass(id);

        TargetClass target = mapper.map(source);

        System.out.println("target: id='" + target.getId() + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your mistake/"trick" is: Why is `ValueObjectMapper` not a (mapstruct) mapper?? Because: "Can't generate mapping method for a generic type variable source." ! ;p

Comment: ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351869/how-to-map-to-generic-type

Comment: in short: Your value mapper maps from `ValueObject<T>` to `T`, but you need (additionally): `ValueObject<X>` to `Y` ..that is the source of ambiguity (`X = UUID`, `Y = String` ;)