# MapStruct @SuperBuilder Return type error not cast

Tags: spring, spring-boot, radix, mapstruct, mapper

BaseDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class BaseDto{
    // Some fields
}
```

TestDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class TestDto extends BaseDto {
    // Some fields
}
```

Base Mapper:

```
@MapperConfig(
        componentModel = "spring"
)
public interface BaseMapper<E extends BaseEntity, DTO extends BaseDto> {
    DTO toDto(E entity);
    ....
}
```

Mapper Generate Impl:

```
@Component
public class TestMapperImpl implements BaseMapper {

    @Override
    public TestDto toDTO(Test entity) {

        BaseDtoBuilder<?, ?> testDto= BaseDto.builder();

        if ( entity != null ) {
            if ( entity.getId() != null ) {
                testDto.id(entity.getId() );
            }
        }
        return testDto.build();
    }
}
```

Mapper create Impl class automatically. Problem is return type.

```
BaseDtoBuilder<?, ?> testDto= BaseDto.builder();
return testDto.build();
```

Intelij give error return type, it must be cast as TestDto. Because of mapper return BaseDto. How can i solve this problem?

Note: if use @Builder, there is no error working fine, this time I can't access parent properties.

Comment: You cannot have generic `@Mapper`s ...you can have "typed" `@Mapper`s extending generic base class/interface..: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57351869/592355

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem with this configuration: [MapStruct and Lombok not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676369/mapstruct-and-lombok-not-working-together#answer-47684351)

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.1</version>
<configuration>
    <source>${java.version}</source>
    <target>${java.version}</target>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        </path>
        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </path>
        <!-- Mapstruct should follow the lombok path(s) -->
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

thanks for your help [xerx593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592355/xerx593)